# I can't figure out my error in my PrimeGenerator

Tags: java

In the output, I get a `9` where I should be getting an `11`!

This occurs after the fifth call to `nextPrime()`. Every other output is correct except for the 5th one! I have been struggling to determine my error for a few hours now. Sorry if my code is sloppy, this is the way my mind figured out the problem! It was a requirement to use the flag controlled loop.

```
public class PrimeGenerator
{
    private int num = 2;

    public PrimeGenerator()
    {
    }
    public int nextPrime()
    { 
        boolean done = false;

        for (int n = num; !isPrime(num); n++)
            num = n;

        if (isPrime(num))
        { 
            done = true;
        }  

        if (done)
        {
            int prime = num;
            num++;
            return prime;
        }
        return num;
    }

   public static boolean isPrime(int n)
   {
       boolean result = true;
       for (int i = 2; n % i == 0 && i < n; i++)
           result = false;
       if (n == 2)
           result = true;
       return result;
   }
}
```

My Tester just calls the `nextPrime()` method and prints the result.

Comment: Your `isPrime` method is broken.

Comment: The `for(int n = num; !isPrime(num); n++) num = n;` is almost certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get 9 instead of 11 because you have mistake in method `isPrime`

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n)
{
       boolean result = true;
       for (int i = 2; n % i == 0 && i < n; i++)
           result = false;
       if (n == 2)
           result = true;
       return result;
}
```

Look for number `9`. 
first iteration: i = 2, result = true

n % i => 9 % 2 = 1, so your loop stops before first iteration and `result` didn't changed.

Try to change method `isPrime` (Updated as commented @John in comments)

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n)
{
       if( n % 2 == 0 ) {
           return false;
       }
       double root = Math.sqrt(n);
       for ( int i = 3; i < root; i+=2 ) {
           if( n % i == 0 ) { 
               return false;
           }
       }
       return true;
}
```

Comment: The loop only needs to go to the square root of n.
Also, you already checked for division by 2.  Start with 3, and only do odd numbers.

double root = Math.sqrt(n);
for (int i=3; i<root; i+=2)

Answer (score 1):

Your `nextPrime` method returns `num` whether or not it is prime. Your code is effectively:

```
if(isPrime(num))
    return num;
}
return num;
```

Answer (score 0):

So the main problem with your code here is the method for checking if a number is prime. According to number theory, you just need to check that the given number is not divisible by any number between 2 and the root of the given number you want to determine is prime. More formally, if you want to check if a number n is prime, you need to check that n is not divisible by any number between 2 and sqrt(n).
An updated method using this number theory fact is below:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n)
{
   int root = (int)Math.sqrt(n);
   for (int i = 2; i <= root; i++) {
       if(n % i == 0) {
           return false;
       }
   }
   return true;
}
```

With this your determination of the prime number would be correct and would be much faster. There are even faster ways of determining primes and generating primes like sieve's algorithm.